# Node mongo bulk update, get the updated columns name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a bulk updation on mongodb in nodejs 
i am facing the following scenario

user can update 20-30 fields at once, possibly he dont update all, he may change 1 or 2 or 5 or maybe all, i want to know exactly which are fields ie, whose value have be over-written with new values.

i need to know this because every field carry a weightage and if they update a particular field then i have to re-calculate the weightage of all the columns and assign it to the user

for example if

`User.update({_id: user_id},{ $set : {key1:value,key2:value,key3:value... }})`

now suppose key3 is over-written but key1 & key2 remains as it is, 
so i want to know that key3 has been over-written.
how can i do that ?

Comment: is it possible if user just send values which they have updated, instead of sending all

Comment: this is now the code looks  
 User.update({_id:req.params.id },{ $set: {
      potential_sell: req.body.potential_sell,
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      username: req.body.username,
      age: req.body.age,
      dob: req.body.dob,
      first_name:req.body.first_name,
      avatar:req.body.avatar ....etc
    }}).exec((err,response)

now please tell me ,how can check which field is updated with new field ??

Comment: @Helpinghand no it is not possible

Comment: You need to query your document (to get previous values) before update operation and loop through each field to see which are different than the updated values.

Comment: i mean new value.

Comment: In case, version is 4.0 & above, it has new:true by default, no need to add.

Answer (score 1):

if you use findOneAndUpdate function for updating, it's possible to retrieve document before updating, with that retrieved value you then can compare it with given document to find out witch fields has been updated.
The update function will be like this:

```
db.collection("Collection Name").findOneAndUpdate({"Find Query"},
    {$set: {"Update Query"}},
    {returnOriginal: true},
    (err, res) => {
        //... Some codes for comparing docs
});
```

The "returnOriginal" option makes the query to return updated document before update operation.